# Gaussian Blur not working for a 2D Image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, filtering, convolution

I'm trying to implement a Gaussian blur within c++ and I've ran into a problem that involves the 2d image not being blurred when ran. The whole process is it loads a fully colored image and changes it to gray-scale, but it should also blur it. I also tried it within a 1d image and the blur worked. I'm using a stencil access pattern to blur the data. Any guidance would be helpful.

Blur pattern code

```
//use the Stencil access pattern to blur the data (1D edge detector)
    tbb::parallel_for(blocked_range<int>(1, n - 1), [&](const blocked_range<int>& range)
    {
        for (int i = range.begin(); i != range.end(); i++)
            floatOutput[i] = floatInput[i - 1] * -2 + floatInput[i] * 0 + floatInput[i + 1] * 2; 
    });
```

Save code

```
std::cout << "Saving image...\n";

    outputImage.convertToType(FREE_IMAGE_TYPE::FIT_BITMAP);
    outputImage.convertTo24Bits();
    outputImage.save("blurred.png");

    std::cout << "...done\n\n";
```

Comment: [-2, 0, 2] is not a blur kernel, it's a 1D edge detector as the comment also says. So it shouldn't work as a 1D blur either. Did you use a different kernel there?

Comment: @harold I don't think I used a different kernel, I just didn't use a 2d blocked range for the 1d image and it worked (Single line blur within the 1d). Is there anyway I could show you my whole code? I am very new to this, so I'm unsure

Comment: Please see [mcve]. There is no way we can point at what you're doing wrong, because we don't see what you're doing. Don't post all of your code, post the **minimal** bit of code that is **complete** (i.e. I can compile and run) and shows the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: The only thing I can see you are doing wrong is in this comment: "to blur the data (1D edge detector)" -- an edge detector and a blur filter are 2 different things. But that's just a nomenclature thing, and doesn't invalidate what you're seeing.